# PHP Upload increased upload / processing time

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload

I am trying to upload files to server using PHP.

I created a simple file input and a submit button and wrote the PHP function to handle that request.
Initially I tried using this library https://github.com/Gargron/fileupload which worked fine, but I thought I might be missing something so I wrote the php code myself.

It is uploading small files instantly. By small I mean maximum 1Mb.

I am looking to upload files up to 2-3GB or maybe bigger.

So I tried an 150Mb file which transferred nearly instantly as I have a very high uplink bandwidth, so it took few seconds to transfer it, but it never never arrived on the server, I haave no idea why, when I am tried with small files, they go directly on the server folder instantly.

I tried with a 25Mb file and the browser showed that the upload is 100% in less than 5 seconds, but then it took 4 minutes for the file to get on the destination folder on the server.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Apache2, PHP v7.3.20.

I checked PHP ini and I increased post_max_size and upload_max_filesize as per my requirements, so I am not sure what I am missing.

HTML Form

```
<form action="pages/upload-video" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="upload">

    </form>
```

PHP function

```
 public function upload_video() {
    $target_dir = VIDEO_PATH;
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

}
```

Next I tried to leave only

```
public function upload_video() {
    print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
}
```

And it takes so much time to execute the function. Not sure whats going on here. Never experienced this before.

Comment: Please add the PHP code you are using to process the file. It's hard to answer your question without seeing your code.

Comment: @SloanThrasher edited. it's just basics. Just want to find out why its taking so long on big files. It should just copy the file from the temporary folder to the destination instantly.

Comment: In linux, you can copy a file (takes time) or move a file (almost instantaneous). What code is in the function ```move_uploaded_file```?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php it is a PHP function

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Have you checked the log to see if it issued a warning? Better yet, setup your code to display any errors or warnings and see if move_uploaded_file is issueing a warning. You could also add code to time how long the function takes to run. These steps would help you determine if that is where the extra time is being spent.

Comment: public function upload_video() {
    print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
} I only left this code in the function. It takes 5 minutes for a 25 Mb file to print_r the $_FILES array info

Comment: You should use javascript and ajax to upload such big files in the server as it takes a lot of time. If the internet speed is slow and takes up a lot of time then the browser also hangs. Your code is ok. But it takes up server resources. Try to write some async code